# Timestamp in mail is always Dec 31 while system time is correct

Tags: mail

The timestamp on all my mail messages is Dec 31 however system time
is correct. What do I need to change?

```
don@don-VGN-NS240E:~$ mail
s-nail version v14.8.6.  Type ? for help.
"/home/don/Maildir": 3 messages 1 new
 O  1 Don                Wed Dec 31 19:00   14/450   test                                          
 O  2 Don                Wed Dec 31 19:00   15/501   NewTest                                       
>N  3 Don                Wed Dec 31 19:00   14/469   test with donmail                             
? q
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a bug, and therefore I would suggest asking this in the [S-nail users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/s-nail-users/).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the /etc/s-nail.rc file to set datefield and this solved the problem. Now 
U 17 Don                     07:10 09-15   14/456   crontest
 U 18 Don                     07:15 09-15   14/456   crontest
 U 19 Don                     07:20 09-15   14/456   crontest
 U 20 Don                     07:25 09-15   14/456   crontest
 U 21 Don                     07:30 09-15   14/456   crontest
 U 22 Don                     07:35 09-15   14/456   crontest

> N 23 Don                     07:40 09-15   14/456   crontest
>    N 24 Don                     07:45 09-15   14/456   crontest
>    N 25 Don                     07:50 09-15   14/456   crontest
>   ?